# Population Mean Estimation using Poisson Regression?

Tags: mean, count-data, poisson-regression, population

Assuming I have count data, where x is the counted variable of interest and y is some total number of counts for a given sample. Then, can I improve my estimate of $\mu_x$ by using a Poisson regression with offset, over simply taking the variance of the ratios to build a confidence interval over the Gaussian?

My model in R would look like this:

```
mean_hat = glm(x~1, offset = log(y), data = data, family = poisson)
exp(confint(mean_hat$coefficients[1]))
```

It would appear to me that preserving the relative sample sizes described by the offset in y is more informative than overriding this information by taking ratios. However, I am unsure if this approach is justified and if other models should be considered.
I much appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 0):

In this model, the assumptions are $X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda Y_i)$ for  $i = 1,...,n$, where $n$ is sample size and $i$ is row number in dataset. $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are known and store in the dataset. We need to estimate the unknown parameter $\lambda$. Following the assumption, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ follows Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, Therefore, $$\hat \lambda = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i} $$.
For the confidence interval of $\lambda$, we can get the limits of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ based on $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ follows Poisson distribution. Then the limits of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ divide by ${\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}$, we get the CI of $\lambda$. For each individual case, the CI is $Y_i$ times CI of $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can I infer the distributional form without model comparison and could a negative binomial be a better fit?

Comment: Yes, you can just say the Poisson distribution. Model generally is used when there are covariates having the effect of you Xs. You do not have covariates, so distribution is enough. I think Poisson is the best one. If you use negative binomial, I have no idea how to use offset Y.

Comment: One aspect I was unsure of is whether information criteria would apply (comparing AIC across various intercept-only models) and if the confint command is correct? I am guessing confint assumes the normal distribution, so would I have to compute my own interval? thank you!

Comment: You do not need AIC, because there is only one intercept-only model. I am not very clear what confint does, but the best method is to get exact CI ($\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$) according to Poisson distribution, and then convert it into what you want.